# Xcode template doesn't pick the variable from popup

Tags: xcode, xctest, xctestcase, xcode-template

I'm writing an XCode template. Everything works perfectly fine if I use text value for the variable:

```
        <dict>
        <key>Identifier</key>
        <string>appName</string>
        <key>Required</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>App name</string>
        <key>Description</key>
        <string>App name desc</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>text</string>
        <key>NotPersisted</key>
        <string>true</string>
        </dict>
```

But it doesn't, if I use popup:

```
        <dict>
        <key>Identifier</key>
        <string>appName</string>
        <key>Required</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>Name</key>
        <string>App name</string>
        <key>Description</key>
        <string>App name desc</string>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>popup</string>
        <key>NotPersisted</key>
        <string>true</string>
        <key>Values</key>
        <array>
            <string>AppX</string>
            <string>AppY</string>
        </array>
        </dict>
```

I'm accessing the variable like that:

```
class ___VARIABLE_appName:identifier___TestCase {}
```

Tried with:

```
___VARIABLE_appName:identifier___
___VARIABLE_appName___
___VARIABLE_appName:value___
```

and still nothing. I can of course just use text, but popup would be really better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to create 2 folders (`AppX` and `AppY`) and store the duplicated templates inside them. The only thing that differs between these 2 files - is `VARIABLE_appName` - but by storing templates in different folders I remove the necessity to have it as a variable. So I hardcoded the value instead.

Instead of just `Template1.swift` I now have:

```
Folder AppX
   -Template1.swift
Folder AppY
   -Template2.swift
```